# How do I return a repeated item from an array only once?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large array, part of which looks like this

```
...
 [u'3767' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'3768' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'3769' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'3770' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'3771' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'3772' u'SS14 3HG']
 [u'4300' u'TA1 4DY']
 [u'4301' u'TA1 4DY']
 [u'4302' u'TA1 4DY']
 [u'4303' u'TA1 4DY']
 [u'4304' u'TA1 4DY']
 ...
```

As you can see the items in the second column repeat multiple times. I need to be able to get only a single instance of every repeated item and its corresponding number (from the 1st column). For example:

```
#output
[u'3767' u'SS14 3HG']
[u'4300' u'TA1 4DY']
```

I initially thought I could create a `for` loop that checks if the current item is the same as the next and if so, return the item and delete the next one. However,

a) I would get a "index out of bounds" error and

b) wouldn't this be quite expensive?

Any ideas?

Comment: `u'SS14 3HG'` has several corresponding numbers: do you want to display only one or all of them ?

Comment: @Begueradj I think you misunderstood; by corresponding numbers I meant the numbers in the 1st column that are on the same row as the item in the 2nd column

Comment: Yes, I know but in the first column there are several corresponding numbers for `u'SS14 3HG'`: so do you want to list them all or only one of them randomly ?

Comment: @Begueradj Oh I see what you mean. Not all of them, any one will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the indexes of the first occurrences of the entries in the second column of your array:

```
>>> indexes = np.unique(myarr[:,1], return_index=True)
(array([u'SS14 3HG', u'TA1 4DY'], 
  dtype='<U8'), array([0, 6]))
```

This returns a tuple: an array of the unique entries of `myarr` and an array of the indexes of the first occurrence of that entry.

You can then return the relevant rows of `myarr` using those indexes:

```
>>> myarr[indexes[1]]
array([[u'3767', u'SS14 3HG'],
       [u'4300', u'TA1 4DY']], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

Comment: No problem at all, glad the answer was of use to you.

Answer (score 2):

If they are already grouped together like that you can use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
[next(v) for g,v in groupby(your_list, lambda x:x[1])]
```

eg:

```
>>> your_list = [[u'3767', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'3768', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'3769', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'3770', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'3771', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'3772', 'SS14 3HG'],
...  [u'4300', 'TA1 4DY'],
...  [u'4301', 'TA1 4DY'],
...  [u'4302', 'TA1 4DY'],
...  [u'4303', 'TA1 4DY'],
...  [u'4304', 'TA1 4DY']]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(v) for g,v in groupby(your_list, lambda x:x[1])]
[[u'3767', 'SS14 3HG'], [u'4300', 'TA1 4DY']]
```

If they are not grouped, since you don't care about which item you take from the first column, you could run the items through a dict:

```
>>> [[v,k] for k,v in {k:v for v,k in your_list}.items()]
[[u'4304', 'TA1 4DY'], [u'3772', 'SS14 3HG']]
```

Comment: They are very probably grouped together: to quote the OP : _" I could create a for loop that checks if the current item is the same as the next"_

Comment: Yes, they are all grouped together like this.

Comment: This is a good answer but since I am more familiar with the method offered in ajcr's answer I have picked that one. However, since I will be looking to improve the perfomance of my program eventually, do you know if your method is faster that ajcr's? I think I will test them out at some point and see for myself.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your main concern, and the items are already grouped, there is a simple and fast numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
 [u'3767', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'3768', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'3769', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'3770', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'3771', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'3772', u'SS14 3HG'],
 [u'4300', u'TA1 4DY'],
 [u'4301', u'TA1 4DY'],
 [u'4302', u'TA1 4DY'],
 [u'4303', u'TA1 4DY'],
 [u'4304', u'TA1 4DY'],
])

items, groups = data.T
flags = np.concatenate(([True], groups[1:]!=groups[:-1]))

print items[flags,0]
```

The sorting performed internally by np.unique is avoided this way, if indeed you do not need it.

Alternatively, if you download the code [here](http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp), you can write:

```
group_by(groups).first(items)
```

which has the same characteristics as the np.unique solution, but is syntactically cleaner.